# Extract String from set position up to certain character

Tags: sql, string, t-sql, substring

I now have a different problem ( see previous question).

The string I have is One/Two/Three/Four/Five

I need to extract after the third / and before the fourth /. The added advantage is that the characters up until the third / are all the same length in the column. I am using  -

```
SUBSTRING (ORGPATHTXT,20,(CHARINDEX('/',(ORGPATHTXT))))
```

But this is still including some text after the 4th / but only passing upto 11 character into the column, which I'm finding very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a third argument to `CHARINDEX` which indicates the position to start the search. You can use it.

```
SUBSTRING(ORGPATHTXT,20,CHARINDEX('/',ORGPATHTXT,20)-20)
```

`20` here is the first position after the 3rd `/` in the string.